# Getting "unauthorized" in IBM Cloudant http loging?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant, loopback4

I have created a IBM Cloudant DB and trying to connect via Legacy HTTP Cookie based authentication, which fails with 401 code.

Why this fails, as I followed every step correctly ?

Request:

```
 url:
  'https://<username>.cloudant.com/_session',
  method: 'POST',
  json: true,
  body:
   { name: '<username>',
     password: '<apiKey>' },
```

Response: 401 Unauthorized

```
{
"error": "unauthorized",
"reason": "Name or password is incorrect."
}
```

Ref:

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-authentication#cookie-authentication

https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/node-js/tutorials/end-to-end-nodejs-application-with-loopback-4-cloudant-and-angular/

Comment: Have you verified that your credentials are correct? Are you using legacy credentials? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/Cloudant?topic=Cloudant-ibm-cloud-public#authentication-methods

Comment: Yes legacy enabled and using the same still 401

Comment: And do you use the generated credentials? Why do you have an API key as password, shouldn't that be an actual password?

Comment: Yes, I am using generated credentials. and As per my understanding apiKey is the password. Is it wrong ?

Comment: ApiKey and regular / legacy password is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

With IBM Cloud IAM, generally, if you need to provide username / password, you either use "apikey" as username and the actual API key as password. Or, if your credentials have include both an API key and a password, you pass on the username and the included password.

Using a username plus an API key as password should result in an error.